# steps required to add a UITableViewController as the detail view of a splitView application

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, detailsview

I am becoming one sad stackoverflow-er (not flower ) :S

I would like to know the explicit steps required to add a UITableViewController as the detail view of a splitViewController using xCode and Interface Builder. This is an iPad application, so it does not have to run on the iPhone

I have gone through a number of tutorials that create UISplitViews, so I understand the concept. But each of these tutorials add a webview, or simple view controller that shows an image.

The left side of the split view shows a list of menu items that I can customize. that's the popover. no problem.

the right side needs to be a UITableViewController that I an descend and ascend that will have menu items based on the button clicked on the left hand popover.

I also looked this link - http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/ but the discussion appears to note that it's a "hack" rather than an recognized workflow.

anyone help a brother programmer out? steps are appreciated.

regards,

Edard

Answer (score 0):

Check out any of the examples on the [net](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=UISplitViewController+examples&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=UISplitViewController+UITableView+detail&cp=40&qe=VUlTcGxpdFZpZXdDb250cm9sbGVyIFVJVGFibGVWaWV3IGRldGFpbA&qesig=AybvYqnTIqvELVgsRsYOfA&pkc=AFgZ2tkZIO0ly1nhhqYFqqdtM5DI1BlXOXI9BBt9SvwklmA0yiIqlba6q8y5rgf2XAECd1ZADKJZN1gC8tyelEte24L_LWqVgg&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=UISplitViewController+UITableView+detail&pbx=1&fp=25a0b2344dc0e416). Then take the detailViewController and turn it into a `UITableViewController`.

Alternatively, you can check out the [UISplitViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Yes I have read those links and the UISplitViewController Class reference (as I implied from my message, apologies if it wasn't clear enough) but as I stated they always put a simple view, a UIWebView or some sort of singular window. I've tried to insert the UITableViewController in (via IB for example) and does not seem to want to drop in.